# multiple calls to types in nginx.conf

Tags: nginx

If I have:

```
# ...
http {
  include mime.types;
  # ...
  types {
  }
}
# ...
```

will the second `types` overwrite the types in the include or append to the mime types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will overwrite, which is a pain. When I've needed to give specific mime-types to specific files, I've done it by having a regex to match only those files, and then overwritten the type map for only those files:

```
location ~* ^.+\.(manifest|appcache)$ {
    types         { }
    default_type  text/cache-manifest;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears this has gotten easier since the question was asked. From https://stackoverflow.com/a/20566966:

> You just need to specify additional types on the same level as your
>   `mime.types` include:
>
> ```
> include mime.types;
> types {
>     # here is additional types
> }
> ```

Comment: its look like user accepted the answer already